# Linphone returns nil ZRTP SAS (authentication token)

Tags: ios, encryption, voip, linphone, linphone-sdk

I'm building a secure VoIP iOS app using the Linphone SDK.

I set up media encryption right when the app starts:

`linphone_core_set_media_encryption(theLinphone.lc, LinphoneMediaEncryptionZRTP)`

And I am trying to retrieve the SAS like this:

`linphone_call_get_authentication_token(Call.current())`

Most times it returns nil. But once in a while it returns a Hexadecimal value like `0x35422f6e6f697461`

I even get this log:
`ortp-message-ZRTP secrets on: SAS is xxxx previously verified no` being "xxxx" the correct SAS.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what was happening.

I was calling `linphone_call_get_authentication_token(Call.current())` immediately after the call state changed to `LinphoneCallOutgoingProgress`. All I had to do to fix it was to start a `Timer` that calls a method every 1 second when the call state changes to `LinphoneCallOutgoingProgress` because it takes sometime for the SAS to be generated it seems. Here's what worked for me:

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        let sas = linphone_call_get_authentication_token(Call.current())

        if sas != nil {

            self!.sasLabel.text = String(cString: sas!)
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
}
```